# Shiny causing dataset in googleVis to have differing number of rows

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use Shiny to create a googleVis Bubble Chart. Outside of the Shiny server this code works fine:

```
df=data.frame(states=gun_stats$new_states, household=gun_stats$Gun.Ownership..2007., murder=gun_stats$Gun.Murder.Rate.per.100K..2010.,
          attack_size=gun_stats$state_attacks,attack_size_group=gun_stats$attack_category,
          gun_stats$x)


Bubble <- gvisBubbleChart(df, idvar="states", xvar="household", yvar="murder",colorvar="attack_size", sizevar="attack_size",
                      options=list(hAxis="{title:'% Housholds with Guns'}",
                                   vAxis="{title: 'Gun muder rate per 100k'}",height="600"))
plot(Bubble)
```

Then I try to put it in a Shiny app as follows:

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    df=data.frame(states=gun_stats$new_states, household=gun_stats$Gun.Ownership..2007., murder=gun_stats$Gun.Murder.Rate.per.100K..2010.,
              attack_size=gun_stats$state_attacks, attack_size_group=gun_stats$attack_category)    

    output$chart <- renderGvis({
    gvisBubbleChart(df, idvar="states", xvar="household", yvar="murder",colorvar="attack_var", sizevar="attack_var",
                    options=list(hAxis="{title:'% Housholds with Guns'}",
                                 vAxis="{title: 'Gun muder rate per 100k'}",height="600"))
    })   
})
```

ui.R

```
library(googleVis)
library(shiny)
pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Mass Shootings Overview"),
     sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("attack_var", "Choose a size metric", 
                    choices = c("x", "attack_size"))
    ),
mainPanel(htmlOutput('chart'))
)
```

However this returns: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 51,0

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, you have `colorvar="attack_var"`, there is no column called "attach_var" in the df. If you want to get the value of `selectInput`, it is in the `input` object (see http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/). In this case you would want `input$attack_var`.

Comment: @mRcSchwering Must have copied that in wrong, thanks, I've changed colorvar and sizevar to input$attack_var but I am still getting the same error